# Visualizar todas la BD de mi motor SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Como puede visualizar todas la BD de mi motor SQL Server, desde consola **sqlcmd**

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para visualizar todas las BDs en SQL Server desde consola **sqlcmd** se puede escribir.

1>select name from sys.databases
2>go

Answer (score 0):

También podemos visualizar todas las BDs con el [procedimiento almacenado `sp_databases`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
> sp_databases
> go
```

Answer (score 0):

Para visualizar todas las bases de datos podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select name from sys.databases " -s ComputerName
```

Sustituye "ComputerName" por el nombre de tu PC o Servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]